Is it possible to execute package wrapped into archive as module
This is the structure:
__init__.py
__main__.py
server.py

Inside __main__.py I use relative imports:
from .server import app

When I zip the directory:
python -m zipapp app_builder

And then try to run it like this I get the error:
python app_builder.pyz


ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

which is expected. I need a way to run the code inside the archive similar to this:
python -m app_builder

which works fine.

Quick search gave me this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64093358/what-is-the-correct-way-to-import-modules-for-standalone-app-created-using-pyth. Doesn't this answer your question?

not really, no, I don't want to import those modules, I want to run them as modules, not as scripts

After digging a bit deeper into this: Just write from server import app.
Explanation: When executing a python zipapp it adds the path to the app to python path. So you can import everything from it by name without problems. Relative imports don't work because python doesn't know about any parent package. If you're interested at how this importing works, there are great answers out there (e.g. here).
Suggestion: To prevent any naming conflicts I think it would be good practice to use a structure like
./
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── server.py
└── __main__.py

And then write the import like from mypackage.server import app.

thanks, but I'd still like to use relative imports... seems like what I'm trying to achieve is not supported

If you really want to use relative imports you must ensure that __package__ is set in __main__.py plus that this package is available from python path. You could achieve this by wrapping all your files into a sub-package (let's call it sub) and then build your archive like python -m zipapp .\app_builder\ -m "sub.__main__:<entry_point_func>" where the last part is the name of your entry point function. Please note that under the hood zipapp creates a __main__.py file at root which then uses the same import behaviour as described in my answer.
